# Magento 2 Product tab link

Tags: magento2, custom, product-view, tabs

I'm trying to add an product tab which only functions as a link href predifined in a custom block. No tab content is needed.

I tried the following:

```
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Customvendor\Custommodule\Block\Product\View\Customtab" name="product.tabs.custom" template="Customvendor_Custommodule::product/view/tab.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
```

With which tab.phtml contains the clickable button html and the link which it gets from the customtab block.

However the only thing it outputs is a tab without a title/name, and the content of tab.phtml outputted in the content area below the tabs when you click on it.

[image]

If anyone could help me further with this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a file `catalog_product_view.xml` in below location

> app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/

With following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.details">
        <block class="NameSpace\ModuleName\Block\Product\View\Extra"
               name="product.view.extra"
               template="NameSpace_Modulename::product/view/extra.phtml"
               after="product.info.overview">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Now you can make proper use of block and template files in the assigned location as per XML to do as required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it does not show up, if i add group="detailed_info" to the custom block it does show up, but again without a title/name and with the tab.phtml outputted in the content area below. I added a picture as how it displays at this moment.